# Should required field have a Null Constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Few new columns needs to be added to an existing table in sql server 2008 R2. New columns are like required field, user can't add a new row without passing any values to those new columns.

In .Net code, there is already a method to validate values before inserting a new record.

Is there an advantage of adding a Not Null constraint on new columns?

Comment: It's like the database is offering to do a job for you that'll avoid little messes in the future and it's offering to do that job *for free*. Why would you *not* take it up on that offer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a column should not allow the value `NULL` then yes, you should most definitely declare `NOT NULL` as part of it's definition. Just because the application handles it now doesn't mean it will later, or that someone will (foolishly) run an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement on your table(s) with `SET ColumnName = NULL`.

Comment: I agree, never leave validation on SQL tables up to the server side code, SQL should always have its own backend defences to handle situations where someone could accidentally (or deliberately) make an unexpected change to your table. Think of it like this, you have front line and backline defences, .net being the front line and SQL Not Null being the backline. Both may do a similar job but you can still have confidence that if someone gets through the front line the backline can handle the problem

Comment: Agreed. I often put validations/constraints on the columns, even though the application handles it. For example, for phone numbers I'll normally add a constraint (`NOT LIKE '%[^0-9 +-]%'`) to ensure that it only contains numbers, whitespace, or a plus or dash. Just in case, again, someone does a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` with direct SQL.